# Python 3 stuck in a loop - simple quiz using a dictionary keys - being driven loopy

Tags: loops, python-3.x, dictionary

I am stuck and this is driving me mad. When the for loop ends and the function end is called all appears good but then I appear to go back into loop and the questions keep coming- think I am going loopy

```
import random
asked=[]
a=''
dic = {
    'England':'london',
    'Ireland' : 'dublin',
    'Italy' : 'rome' ,
    'France' : 'paris',
    'Finland' : 'helsinki' ,
    'Greece': 'athens',
    'Germany' : 'berlin'
    }
def end():

    input("Press the enter key to exit.")

def start(a):

    if len(asked)==len(dic):
     end()
    else:
      a=random.choice(list(dic.keys()))
      if a in asked:
        start(a)
      else:
        asked.append(a)
        main(a)

def main(a):
    for i in dic:
      q=dic[a]
      question=input('What is the capital of ' + a + ' ?')
      question=question.lower()
      if question==q:
        print('That is correct ' , q , ' is the capital of ' , a)
        start(a)
      else:
        print( question , 'is not the correct answer ' , q , ' is the capital of ' , a)
        start(a)
    end()
start(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to be unneeded in your `main` function:

```
for i in dic:
```

This line would cause the question `'What is the capital of ' + a + ' ?'` to be asked multiple times for the same city `a`.

I would recommend you look at [pdb](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pdb.html) - the Python debugger for tracking down simple flow problems like this.

Instead of

```
python3 quiz.py
```

Use

```
python3 -m pdb quiz.py
```

This will give an interactive debugger session. You can set breakpoints for you main and start functions:

```
(Pdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py:29
(Pdb) break start
Breakpoint 2 at c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py:17
```

Then, start running the code with `c` for `continue`. The debugger will stop when it enters one of these functions and show you the line it's up to

```
(Pdb) c
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(19)start()
-> if len(asked)==len(dic):
(Pdb)
```

Enter `n` for `next` to step through the code, or `c` for `continue` to continue running until the next breakpoint.

```
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(22)start()
-> a=random.choice(list(dic.keys()))
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(23)start()
-> if a in asked:
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(26)start()
-> asked.append(a)
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(27)start()
-> main(a)
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(30)main()
-> for i in dic:
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\peter\pytest\quiz.py(31)main()
-> q=dic[a]
```

... etc

Comment: Many thanks Peter. I now understand where I was going wrong.  Mostly works as intended now although my input box is now called 7 times before the program can be ended.  This said I think I am now in a position to sort this out.